# Facebook authentication problems with omniauth 0.2.6 rails ( invalid_credentials)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I get an error when i try to login with facebook via omniauth gem ver.0.2.6. 
It shows invalid_credentials.
http://localhost:3000/auth/failure?message=invalid_credentials
I use this code in initializer/omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook,
           "app_id",
           "app_secret",
           {:scope=>[:email,:user_birthday],:client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => "/etc/ssl/certs"}} }
end

Started GET "/auth/facebook" for 127.0.0.1
Started GET "/auth/facebook/callback?code=0b49kydcswTkMNfx_C9BwhE0Z-g9kO_oE0aJ2F4ghy0.eyJpdiI6IjlYaXRxTF9NdFBGbWtBUk9ZUXVSdUEifQ.DsDgdFUpuC6Z_B_m8j1MiAN1cQRS_Mcr9VvvZvSurs0wUyCRAvjDDEYjE6b6_VUF0KNkeLUy9lJCF2IF2BBGOeAt95fggdI49jZKwqo842z3cdsJQ2kZTQcQrs0jinxn" for 127.0.0.1
```

This all i get. I double checked app_id and app_secret all is ok and tried php version it works fine. So there is no error in this.

So how i can find more info about an error at least ? or how this problem can be fixed ?

Comment: Hey I have worked on the same problem tell me which ruby gem version you are using and also your login system ever worked before you are getting this error?

Comment: Have you try with omniauth (1.1.3) and omniauth-facebook (1.4.0) ?